# Why alert is not working though event is fired?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, live

when I have tried to construct jquery-ui datepicker dynamically for future row of table. I found something weird. The code below is the issue.

```
$('#emp-table').live('focus','.obj-datepicker'function(){
        alert('this is not working though function work');
        $(this).datepicker({
            isActiveX: true
        }).next('a').click(function() { 
            $(this).prev().eq(0).datepicker("show"); 
        });
    })
```

I have googled this wierd issue but failed to figure it out.

> **Why alert is not working though event is fired???**

Comment: update the question with the error trace from django. 500 can mean anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#emp-table').live('focus','.obj-datepicker'function(){
```

Is this the exact code for you testing? I think a comma is missed after `'.obj-datepicker'`, you can delete and try again.

Comment: :) That's okay. You should check the console first in Chrome or other browsers. Then you will find the error.